# Problem with CSS and Floats

Tags: css

I have a box where I am trying to add a button to the bottom right corner, yet when I try to float it right, it ends up outside of the div that I have placed it in. How can I fix this?

[Link To Live Example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5821809/carta/so_text.html)

Code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #sidebar {
            width: 340px;
            float:left;
        }

        .side_block {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            padding:8px;
            margin: 8px;
            border-radius: 12px;
            border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
        }
        .addLink{
            float:right;
            font-size:12px;
        }   
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div class="side_block">

                        <h4>Files</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Original Emails.doc</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Homepage Draft.jpg</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">First_Draft.txt</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <input type="button" class="addLink" value="+Add File" style="float:right;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your float:

```
<div class="side_block">

            <h4>Files</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Original Emails.doc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Homepage Draft.jpg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">First_Draft.txt</a></li>
            </ul>
            <input type="button" class="addLink" value="+Add File" style="float:right;">
            <br style="clear: right;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow:hidden; zoom:1;` to `.side_block` to [clear your float](http://work.arounds.org/clearing-floats/).

Comment: +1 for the link. I've heard the term 'clearing floats' before, but this helped understand exactly what that is and why it needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<body>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div class="side_block">
      <input type="button" class="addLink" value="+Add File" style="float:right;">
      <h4>Files</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Original Emails.doc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Homepage Draft.jpg</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">First_Draft.txt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```